# Create form dynamically in table

Tags: php, javascript, html

Using some code to create a form dynamically which I got here: http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript2/createSelectDynamically.htm

This works great.  However I have a regular html table I generate with html/php to get data out of a DB.  I want to replace that data with a form so when users click the edit button the original entry is replaced with a form (either textbox or pull down menu).  The user makes a selection and the new table comes back with the appropriate edit.

So for example one part of the data has this in the table:

```
<td><?php echo $result[0] ?></td>
```

Using the link about to create a form dynamically I change this to:

```
<td id="paraID"><form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action enctype="text/plain" alt=""><?php echo $result[0] ?></form></td>
```

Also note the onclick event for the edit button:

This is hard to explain but hoping someone can help me with this interaction.  I need some way to say:
    if (user clicks edit button)
    then 
    replace html table with form for each entry (for example, the table returns a name called foo and a textbox will appear with foo in it but now they can edit to change the name).

Comment: Per chance, you wouldn't be using jQuery or consider using it would you? It makes doing things like this easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can start out with an id for the td then it will make things easier. Then you will need an edit button somewhere. Notice: It might be nice to replace "result_0" with the name for the value/field:

```
<td id="result_0_parent"><?php echo $result[0] ?><input type="button" onClick="editField('result_0','select')" value="Edit" /></td>
```

Then in your javascript you will have the editField function defined so that it sets the content of the td to be the dynamic form. Looking at `makeForm` function in the example javascript, you see this happening with `appendChild(myform);` The function `editField` will be like the `makeForm` function except you will pass in the field_id and field_type as parameters:

```
function editField(field_id, field_type)
```

I suggest you change the line that defines `mypara` to define `mytd` or better yet, `field_parent` instead since in your case it will not be a paragraph element, but a td (or possibly some other type of element):

```
field_parent = document.getElementById(field_id+"_parent");
```

The example code create a select (dropdown), but I am guessing you want to create other field input types so I recommended having field_type as a second parameter to the function. This means that it would make more sense for your implementation to use `myfield` instead of `myselect` and then use the field_type parameter to decide what `myfield` will be.

Replace the line in the makeForm / editField function:

```
myselect.setAttribute("id","selectID");
```

with

```
myfield.setAttribute("id",field_id);
```

One more thing: To set the initial value of the input field to be the displayed content, you will need to copy the "innerHTML" of the "parent" element. So place something like this right after defining field_parent:

```
initial_value = field_parent.innerHTML;
```

and I think you can figure out the rest. If not, I can elaborate a little more.

Answer (score 0):

> This works great. However I have a regular html table I generate with
>   html/php to get data out of a DB. I want to replace that data with a
>   form so when users click the edit button the original entry is
>   replaced with a form (either textbox or pull down menu). The user
>   makes a selection and the new table comes back with the appropriate
>   edit.

This is a script that allows with a double click on values to edit them and has a button to send them back. Maybe it would be of some help to use it (or use parts of it).

```
<?PHP
if(count($_POST)>0)
{
    echo 'You gave:<br><per>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '<a href=http://localhost/temp/run.php>Start over</a>';
    exit; 
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

/**formEditor Class
*/
function formEditorCls( ) 
{ 
        /**
            Constructor simulator
        */ 
          this.lastFieldEditedId = null; 


        /** Change span with input box, hide the eddit button and store theses IDS
        */
        this.edit=
        function  (field)
        {    
            //if there was a field edited previously
            if(this.lastFieldEditedId != null)
                  this.save();
            //get the inner element of the div, it can be span or input text 
            var childElem = document.getElementById(field).getElementsByTagName('*')[0];  
            //then replace the span element with a input element
            document.getElementById(field).innerHTML="<input type=text name=n_"+field+ 
                " id=id_"+field+" value="+childElem.innerText+">";    
            //store what was the last field edited
            this.lastFieldEditedId =field; 

        }//func

        this.save=
        function  ()
        { 
            dbq="\"";sq='\''; 
             //get the last value
             var lastValue = document.getElementById(this.lastFieldEditedId).
             getElementsByTagName('*')[0].value;  
            //store it as span 
            document.getElementById(this.lastFieldEditedId).innerHTML="<span  ondblclick="+dbq+
            "formEditor.edit("+sq+this.lastFieldEditedId+sq+");"+dbq+" >"+lastValue+"</span>" ;
            //now must reset the class field attribute
            this.lastFieldEditedId=null; 
        }//func

        this.submit=
        function  (path)
        { 
            this.save();//if ay field was edited put new values in span elements

          var form = document.createElement("form");//create a new form
            form.setAttribute("method", "post");
            form.setAttribute("action", path); 
            var myDiv = document.getElementById( "fieldsDiv" );//get the div that contains the fields
            var inputArr = myDiv.getElementsByTagName( "SPAN" );//get all span elements in an array
            //for each span element

            for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++)
            {
                var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");//create an input elemet
                hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("name", i);
                hiddenField.setAttribute("value", inputArr[i].innerText);
                form.appendChild(hiddenField);//append the input element
            }
            document.body.appendChild(form);//append the form  
            form.submit();//submit the form 

        }//func

}//class

formEditor =    new formEditorCls( ); 
</script>

</head>
<body onclick="rt();">

Double click any value to change it..<br><br>
<div id="fieldsDiv">

Name:<font id="nameField">
<span  ondblclick="formEditor.edit('nameField');" >Mark</span> 
</font><br>

Surname:<font  id="surnameField" >
<span ondblclick="formEditor.edit('surnameField');">Smith</span> 
</font><br>

</div> 
<input type=submit name="submit"  
onclick="formEditor.submit('http://localhost/temp/run.php');" value="Submit">

</body> 
</html>
```